# Overriding destroy() to remove photos associated with model doesn't remove model itself

Tags: backbone.js, titanium, titanium-alloy

In my Appcelerator Titanium Alloy project, I’m attempting to override `model.destroy()` to remove photos associated with the model. My code removes the photos just fine, but doesn’t actually delete the model. What am I doing wrong?

```
_.extend(Model.prototype, {
    destroy: function (options) {
        // override default destroy method to also remove photos
        console.log('destroying the model');
        var model = this;
        options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
        var photos = JSON.parse(model.get('photos'));
        photos.forEach(function (photo) {
            console.log("Deleting photo: " + photo);
            var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, photo);
            f.deleteFile();
        });
        model.trigger('destroy', model, model.collection, options);
    }
});
```

I see the console log statements, and the photos are removed. But the model remains.

Some things I've tried, without success:

In my controller, calling both of these:

```
model.destroy();
collection.remove(model);
// also collection.remove([model]);
```

I've tried adding this to my extended destroy function but it didn't work

```
   ...
   f.deleteFile();
});
model.collection.remove(model);
// and model.collection.remove([model]);
model.trigger('destroy', model, model.collection, options);
```

With the following, the model is destroyed, but my code doesn't run and the photos aren't deleted.

```
_.extend(Model, {
...
```

Comment: It seems to work as is, https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/Lyvn6dep/ , at least without Titanium

Comment: It seems to be specific not only to Titanium, but perhaps on iOS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your Model object and not the prototype.

```
destroy: function (options) {
    // override default destroy method to also remove photos
    console.log('destroying the model');
    var model = this;
    options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
    var photos = JSON.parse(model.get('photos'));
    photos.forEach(function (photo) {
        console.log("Deleting photo: " + photo);
        var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, photo);
        f.deleteFile();
    });
    Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! For anyone looking at this later, the key difference is calling `Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this);` at the end rather than `model.trigger()` And note that Eric's code would go inside the `_.extend({})` call in your model definition.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: any chance that the `options` passed to your extended `destroy(...)` method include `{ wait: true }`?  If so the model won't be removed from the collection [until the server responds with a `sync` event](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy).

The way you've overridden `destroy(...)`, that will never happen.